# Como eu poderia adicionar um ICONE dentro de um SELECT em HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

Olá, gostaria de adicionar ícones (de fonte, como a bootstrap por exemplo) dentro de um campo select no HAML, a princípio estou fazendo assim, isso seria possível? Pensei em usar o list-dropdown do bootstrap como medida paleativa,porém, também não deu muito certo...

```html
- icons = ["icon-world", "icon-star-twohdd-o", "icon-users"] 
    %label.control-label
      = Activity.ht("activity_status_situation")
    %select{style: 'max-width: 300px; min-width: 150px', name: 'icons_milestone'}
      - for icon in icons do
        %option{value: "#{icon}", type: "", selected: ("")}
          %i.#{icon}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira,

Primeiro, adicionei a linha de scape markup,

```html
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-select-icons").select2({
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      escapeMarkup: function(m) { 
         return m; 
      }
    });
  });
```

Segundo, ao invés de fechar com '<' e abrir com '>' no select, foi aberto com o tag HTML da seguinte forma:

```html
   %select.js-select-icons{style: 'min-width: 50px', name: 'icons_milestone'}
  - for icon in icons do
     %option{value: "#{icon}", type: "", selected: ("")}
       = "&lt;i class='#{icon}'>&lt;/i>".html_safe
```

Desta forma, funcionou perfeitamente! E ficou da seguinte forma,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que ajude e que ficou claro...